# JPA tables are ID is mandatory?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I saw that the ID type is defined in every JPA table. Is it mandatory?
Or is there any option that I can get class without the ID member?

Comment: Its not mandatory in JDO, in that you can have tables without primary key (see "nondurable identity"), but is in JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id(i.e. primary key) is mandatory in JPA. As JSR317(Java Persistence API, which could be downloaded [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)) chapter 2.4 said(first sentence):

```
Every entity must have a primary key
```

BTW, besides `Id` annotation, one can also use `EmbeddedId` annotation for composite primary keys.

Comment: And the type of the ID can be any type ? I tried to find the documentation without success

Comment: JPA poses some restrictions on ID type(e.g. primary key class must be serializable), you can read the specification from the link I gave for more details,(esp. chapter 2.4 which I mentioned in the answer).

Answer (score 3):

Id is required by JPA, but it is not required that the Id specified in your mapping match the Id in your database.

For instance you can map a table with no id to a jpa entity. To do it just specify that the "Jpa Id" is the combination of all columns.

Note that for performence reason, it's important to have a good index on column(s) specified as Id in Jpa